# Align Sub Figures in latex (IEEE paper format)

Tags: latex, figure, ieee, subfigure

I want to align three figures in one row. I used the following latex code but got this output.  What to change in this code to get these figures in one row? Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\begin{document}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{figure*}[!h]
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Paper/results.PNG}
    \caption{Fig_1} \label{fig1}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Paper/results.PNG}
    \caption{Fig_2} \label{fig2}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Paper/results.PNG}
    \caption{Fig_3} \label{fig3}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Figures}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

This is a two-column paper
[Output I get from the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2iHP.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of 3 times `.5\textwidth` is much bigger than the available space on one line. If you want to fit all three images in a single line, make them smaller:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts


\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!h]
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Fig1} \label{fig1}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Fig2} \label{fig2}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Fig3} \label{fig3}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Figures}
\label{fig:mylabel}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]